# Draggable containment option of jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My HTML is:

```
<div id="inside">
 <p id="drag">drag me </p>
</div>
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$('#drag').draggable({containment: 'parent'});
```

It is not working. It is only moving along the y axis, as if it is reacting to `{axis: 'y'}`.

It is even reacting the same way for `{containment: 'document'}` and `{containment: 'window'}`

Comment: Fixed the problem , had to set the  width and the height of the elements. It will not work if the width and the height are not set.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be setting the properties of the elements properly.
A working fiddle:

```
<div class="container">
<p id="draggable">I'm contained within my parent</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKSN5/1